# PHP- How to merge/join MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to merge two tables in PHP using MySQLi queries. I have a database with a table2 which contains: Country|Region(means Continent)|Value|Area(means Total, Rural or Urban)

[image]

I need to sum the values by region so I execute:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  Country, Region, SUM(Value) as Value2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.Area='$area' GROUP BY (table2.Region IN ($region)) ");
```

$query1 contains 5 rows with the corresponding values of the continents.
Now, I want to obtain a table with all the countries and their corresponding Continen Values, I mean , if I have Spain in table2 with its value, now I want Spain with the aggregated European value associated.

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Country,Region FROM table2 WHERE Region IN ($region)");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Country,Value FROM $result INNER JOIN $query1 ON $result.Region = $query1.Region");
```

I think that the error is that I'm using $result as a table and maybe this object is not a table, but I don't know. I get a fatal error executing the last query and it doesn't work.

How can I get a table with the Value aggregated (obtained in query1) and the different countries?I think that the main problem is the sintax with the variables and the structure of the query result

Comment: Please post your table definitions including the primary keys for each. You need to read about how to construct a `join` - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: I added it above :) I have read about join but I'm not sure that I use it correctly with PHP variables

Comment: You only added a screenshot of table content. Please, when asking questions, try to always add the CREATE TABLE sentence for that table. This way, others can see the data types used, where are the indexes, primary key, foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. This is how I understand your question now. I have 1 table named `table2`. I have a query which groups rows by `region` and then sums their `value`. I want a new query which groups by `region` and also `country` and want it to sum that `value`. I also want to filter that query by `country`. Is that right? If not, please update your question so that it is clear.

Comment: The new query should join the result of the last one and table2 in order to obtain all the countries and their corresponding aggregated values by continent(obtained in the first query)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new in XAMPP and I don't know how to get the CREATE TABLE

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what a `join` does. It does not group multiple queries together.

If I understand your question correctly, then you only have 1 table, named `table2`. In this case, you *probably* don't need a `join`.

If you want to see the `country`, `region`, and its `sum` of values then you can `group by` `Country` and `Region`.

```
SELECT Country, Region, sum(Value) 
FROM table2 
GROUP BY Country, Region
WHERE Region = 'Europe and Central Asia'
;
```

If you want to see the `region` and its `sum` of values then you can `group by` `Region`.

```
SELECT Region, sum(Value) 
FROM table2 
GROUP BY Region
;
```

If this is not what you want, then please edit your question and show us an example of the **desired output**. As it currently stands, your requirements are not clear.

Example of desired output which would help us answer your question.

```
+-------------------------+------+
|         Region          | Sum  |
+-------------------------+------+
| Europe and Central Asia | 68.0 |
| Africa                  | 59.5 |
| Arab States             | 46.0 |
+-------------------------+------+
```